# PHP: change password

Tags: php, change-password

I am implementing a password change function for my website. Unofortunately it doesn't work.

In the .html file I got the code:

```
 <form method='post' >
                    <td>Old Password:</td>                  
                    <td><input name='oldpw' type='password' required='required'/></td>
                <tr>
                    <td>New Password:</td>
                    <td><input name='newpw' type='password' required = 'required' /></td>
                <tr>                    
                    <td>Confirm Password:</td>                  
                    <td><input name='conpw' type='password' required = 'required' /></td>
                    <td> 
                    <input type='submit' value='Change Password' />
                    </td>
                </tr>           
                 </form>
```

In the account.php file I wrote this:

```
if (isset($_POST['newpw'])){

    $pw=$dbc->query("select passwort from kundenaccount where accname= '" . $_SESSION['accname'] . "';")
                $row = $pw->fetch_object()
                $pawo = $row->passwort 

        if (md5($_POST['oldpw']) == $pawo){
        if ($_POST['newpw']==$_POST['conpw']){
         $dbc->query("UPDATE accname SET passwort='" . md5($_POST['newpw']) . "' WHERE accname='" . $_SESSION['accname'] . "';")
         }
        else { echo "Passwords do not match" }
        }
    else { echo "Wrong password entered"}
    }
```

Do anyone see my mistake? I try to solve this problem since days..

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text or md5. Also you can try to remove the @ you have everywhere that shouldn't be used. You should handle errors, not suppress them.

Comment: Your form doesn't have a action

Comment: first step, **STOP** supressing errors with `@`. if the code doesn't work, then DON'T do the equivalent of stuffing fingers in your ears and going 'la la la la'.

Comment: @user2067005: not necessary. if no action is specified, the form submits to the url the form was loaded from.

Comment: @Marc B form is not on same page. So how does his .html know exactly to send it to the account.php file, please, tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your form:

```
 <form method='post' action='account.php'>
```

UPDATE:

I went through and made the script for my database, works fine. change values where needed:

```
<?php
$dbc = new mysqli("localhost", "db-user", "db-pass", "db-name");
if (isset($_POST['newpw'])){
    $pw=@$dbc->query("select passwort from kundenaccount where accname= '" . $_SESSION["accname"] . "'");
                $row = $pw->fetch_object();
                $pawo = $row->password ; 

    if (md5($_POST['oldpw'])== $pawo){

        if ($_POST['newpw']==$_POST['conpw']){
         @$dbc->query("UPDATE kundenaccount SET passwort='" . md5($_POST['newpw']) . "' WHERE accname='" . $_SESSION['accname'] . "'");
         }
        else { echo "Passwords do not match"; }
        }

    else { echo "Wrong password entered";}
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_POST['oldpw']==md5($pawo))
```

should be

```
if (md5($_POST['oldpw']) == $pawo)
```

Answer (score 0):

md5 is a one way hash so you cannot undo it, you should compare the other way.

```
if (md5($_POST['oldpw'])==$pawo){
```

NOTE: MD5 is not considered secure, I would upgrade to some other algorithm..

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the problem

```
 <?php

 include ('connect_db.php');
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
       $oldpw = $_POST ['oldpw'];
 $newpw = $_POST ['newpw'];
 $retypepw = $_POST ['retypepw'];

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '$oldpw'") or die (mysql_error());
   if ($sql)

   {
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
       extract ($row);

       if ($oldpw <> $password) {
           echo "Passwords dont match";}

           else

       if ($newpw == $retypepw){
        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET  password = '$newpw' WHERE password = '$oldpw' ") or die (mysql_error());
            if($update)

    {

        echo "Successfully changed password"; }
        }

    else { echo "Password dont match";}

       }

   }
    ?>
```